# Performance degradation after upgrading to MySQL 8

Tags: performance, mysql-8.0, upgrade

We have upgraded MySQL in our application from version 5.7.43 to version 8.0.35.
We are getting below exception while trying the fetch the records from the database.

> ```
> 231104 04:04:03 : com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: 
>                   Application was streaming results when the connection failed. 
>                   Consider raising value of 'net_write_timeout' on the server.
> 231104 04:04:03 : at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
> 231104 04:04:03 : at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
> 231104 04:04:03 : at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
> 231104 04:04:03 : at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
> ```

We tried increasing the `net_write_timout` value but it didnt help.
Could anyone please provide your suggesstions?